# GCSFuse, Docker and Apple Silicon

Tags: docker

I just got a Mac Mini with the new M1 chip to use as a dev machine. My app uses gcsfuse.

When I attempt to install gcsfuse within the Debian stretch based container using "apt-get install gcsfuse-stretch", I get "Unable to locate package gcsfuse-stretch".

This is the same workflow I use to install gcsfuse on the same Debian stretch based container on my older Mac laptop.

The only difference that I can see that the 'arch' command inside the container on the older latop returns 'x86_64' while 'arch' return 'aarch64' on the new Mac Mini.

My question: Is it possible to install and run gcsfuse on a container hosted on Apple silicon? Or do I need to wait for a new release of gcsfuse that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

The error is not related to the difference between the CPU architectures but rather more on failing to locate a certain package.  I get the similar error when I run `sudo apt-get install gcsfuse-stretch` on my Debian Stretch VM.

First, please make sure that you're exactly following this [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#ubuntu-and-debian-latest-releases). I will write it here:

1. Add the gcsfuse distribution URL as a package source and import its public key (important):

```
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

2. Update the list of packages available and install gcsfuse:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
```

For updated information, please check the [release](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/gcsfuse-stretch/Release) documentation. There you can see that gcsfuse supports `arm64` (such as M1 chips). You can see the same output on your terminal by running `uname -a`.